# Why Int Does Not Implement 'Monoid'?

Tags: haskell

Given a `Maybe Int`, I tried to `mappend` it to itself.

```
$let x = Just 55 :: Maybe Int

$mappend x x

<interactive>:126:1:
    No instance for (Monoid Int) arising from a use of `mappend'
    In the expression: mappend x x
    In an equation for `it': it = mappend x x
```

Looking at [Maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html), I see:

> Monoid a => Monoid (Maybe a)

Since [Int](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Int.html) does not implement `Monoid` type-class, that explains why I can't use `mappend` with `Maybe Int`.

But, I remembered from [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) that I can use `Sum`:

```
ghci> let x = Sum 55
ghci> mappend x x
Sum {getSum = 110}
```

But, why isn't `Int` a Monoid?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`Int` isn't a `Monoid` because there's more than one obvious `Monoid` implementation for `Int`.

```
instance Monoid Int where
    mempty  = 0
    mappend = (+)

instance Monoid Int where
    mempty  = 1
    mappend = (*)
```

The `newtype`s [`Sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#v:Sum) and [`Product`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#v:Product) defined in `Data.Monoid` allow you to easily select which `Monoid` instance to use with numbers.

Comment: @KevinMeredith If you're using GHC 7.8 or newer then `Sum` and `Product` implement `Num`, so you can do `getSum $ mconcat $ take 10 $ iterate (+1) 1`, although they don't implement `Enum` so you can't do `getSum $ mconcat [1..10]`.  In the first expression you can swap `getSum` for `getProduct` and it'll still compile.

Comment: Other valid monoid implementations: max and min (with mempty being minBound and maxBound respectively).  There are _lots_ of valid implementations.

Comment: ... not to mention that it could be minimum, maximum, first positive number, and so on.

Comment: Since `Int` is fixed size, we also have various bitwise operations.

Comment: @augustss The other good fundamental theorem of arithmetic related `Monoid` instance for `Integral` types would be (signed) `lcm` with identity `1`. A `gcd` instance also needs to be signed to obey the identity laws for identity `0`.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis Many of the bitwise operations work for `Integer`s as well.

Comment: You could even interpret Integer or Int as members of equivalence classes mod primes and pick up even more fun.

Comment: I think it's an interesting and not always obvious question of what rules to follow when a type allows multiple lawful instances of the same class . In some cases, like `Int` and `Monoid` here, the choice has been not to implement the class at all, and leave the instances to `newtype`s, because there's no obvious choice of one as the default. In the case of the `Applicative []` instance, on the other hand, only one of them is compatible with the `Monad` instance, which determines the choice. Then there are cases like `Monoid Maybe` instance which many people dislike...

Comment: Many types have class instances that have multiple possible implementations and it seems we just pick one of them, so why havent we picked one for the Int Monoid?